# Pug - Access data from server in pug script(type='text/javascript')

Tags: javascript, node.js, chart.js

I am trying to load data from the server in my pug template.

My route looks like the following:

```
app.get('/serverdata', async(req, res) => {

  const chartData = []
  for (const i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    chartData.push(Math.random() * 50)
  }

  const result = JSON.stringify(chartData)

  res.render('serverdata', {
    result,
  })
})
```

My pug template looks like the following:

```
  .row
    .col-md-12
      .card
        .embed-responsive.embed-responsive-16by9
          canvas#myNewChart(style='display: block; width: 1000px; height: 500px;', width='1000', height='500')      

block specific-js
  script(type='text/javascript', src="js/plugins/chart.js") 
  script(type='text/javascript').
    var data = {
      labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
      datasets: [
        {
          label: "My First dataset",
          fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.2)",
          strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
          pointColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
          pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
          pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
          pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
          data: result //here I am getting the error
        }
      ]
    };

    var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");
    var myNewChart = new Chart(ctx).Line(data);
```

My error is within my view file:

```
serverdata:13 Uncaught ReferenceError: result is not defined
    at serverdata:13
```

Any suggestions how to load server data in the `script.` tag of my pug file?

I appreciate your replies!

Comment: The `res.render` should look like this `res.render('serverdata', { result: result })` and i think(i'm not using pug myself) that in your pug file you should use `#{ result }`

Answer (score 1):

I think you are mixing different contexts. The line that gives you an error is executed in the browser, and in that context, there is no variable named `result`.

Since you have a endpoint `/serverdata` on your server in place, all you need to load and parse the data from that URL. Details depend on what kinds of JavaScript libraries you are using, but with [jQuery getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/):

```
$.getJSON("/serverdata", function(data) {
    /* Update your chart by using 'data' */
});
```